# To plot a theoretical density over an empirical density

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I want to plot an empirical density, I would go:

`library(ggplot2) ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x = rbeta(100,3,1)))`

or

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = rbeta(100,3,1)))
```

where `rbeta(100,3,1)` can be any vector.

If I want to plot a theoretical density, I could go:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 1)), mapping = aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dbeta, args = c(3,1), n = 100)
```

But when I try to plot the first curve over the second:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(0, 1)), mapping = aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = dbeta, args = c(3,1), n = 100) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = rbeta(100,3,1)))
```

I will get an error.

How can I plot an empirically determined density over a theoretical?

Comment: Don't you want the line *above* the histogram? If you plot the line before, it will be covered by the histogram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work.
Plot the histogram first, then the density. And with more data points the histogram fits the theoretical density better.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(2022)

p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = rbeta(100,3,1), y = ..density..), bins = 30) +
  stat_function(fun = dbeta, args = c(3,1), n = 100)

p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = rbeta(10000,3,1), y = ..density..), bins = 30) +
  stat_function(fun = dbeta, args = c(3,1), n = 100)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>